# Countering false positives in GWAS due to linkage disequilibrium

Tags: regression, correlation, genetics

We know that due to LD, we can get significant p-values for markers near a causal marker (or a marker closes to the causal region) in [GWAS](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Genome-wide_association_study) studies. I've seen [attempts](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2276357/?tool=pubmed) looking at LD to do multiple testing correction, by counting the effective number of tests, but as far as I know, they are simply trying to fix the correct global p-value cutoff for a certain error rate. My question is regarding the actual problem of selecting causal markers. What attempts have their been to remove these false positives that occur due to them being in LD with the causal markers? It seems regression and penalized regression will remove some correlated markers, but are their any techniques other than penalized regression to remove these false positives? Regression is obviously also intractable when we have a large number of markers.

Comment: In a general setting Benjimini and Hochsberg have proposed multiple testing procedures for controlling the **false discovery rate**, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate, that may be useful for you here.

Comment: @Macro, no I understand that people have looked at LD for multiple testing correction (and FDR is part of that). My question is are there specific ways to identify the false positives getting low p-values in independent tests due to LD? Or approaches other than penalized regression to identify only the strongest markers within strongly correlated marker sets?

Comment: Of note, penalized regression will not perform in the same way depending on whether you consider L1 (lasso) penalty or the elasticnet criteria (L1+L2).